# Preg_match exact word (UA google tag)

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I'm trying to match the exact UA tag with a curl and preg_match
here is my code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://symfony.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'UA checker');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $chaine = "UA-89393-6;
```

Chaine being the UA tag entered by the user in DB.

```
    preg_match('~\b'.$chaine.'\b~', $result);
```

UA-89393-5 return false

UA-8939 return false

UA-89393- return true

UA-89393 return true

is there something wrong with my regex ? 
how can i find the exact match of the UA string even after the dash ?

Comment: What is the exact content of `$chaine`?

Comment: where does `$tag` come from?

Comment: i've updated my asnwer with a concrete example

Comment: Still not reproducible, https://3v4l.org/4tgc6.

Answer (score 0):

> Chaine being the UA tag entered by the user in DB.

If you're looking for an exact match of the tag the user entered, don't use regex. Just use `strpos()`:

```
if (strpos($result, $chaine) !== false) {
    // found it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Preface

The best solution was given to you by Alex. This is not necessarily a good place to use regex, but it doesn't mean it's impossible. The reason regex is not really suitable for this is due to the multiple regex's that would be ideally needed for this (or the dynamic nature of your question, which requires parsing two string separately).

### Answer

Since, however, you are looking for a regex-based solution, I've decided to come up with some ***regex hackery***. This method would require you to concatenate the two UA codes on either side of a unique delimiter that would not show up in the UA codes. For simplicity, I've chosen `||`.

Here is the regex that I've used to parse the UA codes and ensure they match according to your specifications.

> Assuming the $chaine = UA-00000000-1
>
> UA-00000000-0 return false
>
> UA-0000000 return false
>
> UA-00000000- return true
>
> UA-00000000 return true

Note: Ensure that you are using the `g` and `m` modifiers if you want to test against multiple using newline characters to delimit the end of a line.

#### Concatenation

Assuming the simplest version of your code...

```
$chaine = 'UA-00000000-1';
$match = 'UA-00000000'; // or any other value
$delimiter = '||';

$string = "{$chaine}{$delimiter}{$match}";
// perform regex match against the above $string
```

#### Regex

```
^(UA-\d+)(-)(\d+)\|\|\1\2?((?=\3).*)?$
```

#### Functionality

1. Match `UA-` followed by between one and unlimited digits
2. Match `-`
3. Match between one and unlimited digits
4. Match the delimiter `||`
5. Match the first capture group (1.)
6. Match the second capture group (2.) between zero and one times
7. Match any character between zero and unlimited times if it matches the third group (3.) - between zero and one times

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/5DRAuJ/1) is an example of the regex being used against the concatenated strings.